# What exactly is a data source? What difference does it make?

Tags: java, jdbc, jdbc-odbc

When I tried to establish a connection with the Oracle Database, I had to write

```
Connection CON = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Dan", "system", "noodles");
```

Here, `Dan` is the data source name, isn't it? What if I created a table called `cBC` when the data source was `Dan` and what if I rename the data source and enter further rows into the table? What difference does it make?

Answer (score 2):

`Dan` is the name of a ODBC connection configured on your machine. The name itself does not matter, as long as the database that it is configured to connect to is the same, it doesn't matter if you call it `Dan`, `MyDatabase` or `foobar`.

Note that this specific way to access a database that is configured externally is not a thing that JDBC does in general, it's a specific behaviour of the JDBC-ODBC bridge (which lets you access ODBC connections via JDBC).

Other JDBC drivers (such as MySQL) use a different syntax where the necessary configuration for accessing the database is encoded in the URL: `jdbc:mysql://myDbServer/myDbName`.

Note also that the [JDBC-ODBC bridge](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html) was never intended for production-quality DB connections (it will even be removed in Java 8!). It is just a quick way to use an existing setup.

For Oracle DB connections you should instead use the [appropriate Type 4 driver from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html). Those drivers use an URL in the form `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//<host>:<port>/ServiceName` (generally speaking, the part after `jdbc:` identifies the JDBC driver to be used).